# How to using the Display manager commands of android DisplayManager service by adb command

Tags: java, android, adb

How to using the Display manager commands of android DisplayManager service  by adb command
I want to know how to using the following command to debug android service

```
60      public void onHelp() {
61          final PrintWriter pw = getOutPrintWriter();
62          pw.println("Display manager commands:");
63          pw.println("  help");
64          pw.println("    Print this help text.");
65          pw.println();
66          pw.println("  set-brightness BRIGHTNESS");
67          pw.println("    Sets the current brightness to BRIGHTNESS (a number between 0 and 1).");
68          pw.println("  reset-brightness-configuration");
69          pw.println("    Reset the brightness to its default configuration.");
70          pw.println("  ab-logging-enable");
71          pw.println("    Enable auto-brightness logging.");
72          pw.println("  ab-logging-disable");
73          pw.println("    Disable auto-brightness logging.");
74          pw.println("  dwb-logging-enable");
75          pw.println("    Enable display white-balance logging.");
76          pw.println("  dwb-logging-disable");
77          pw.println("    Disable display white-balance logging.");
78          pw.println("  dwb-set-cct CCT");
79          pw.println("    Sets the ambient color temperature override to CCT (use -1 to disable).");
80          pw.println();
81          Intent.printIntentArgsHelp(pw , "");
82      }
```

Comment: the command help from frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/display/DisplayManagerShellCommand.java

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
adb shell cmd display
```

to get help message

Answer (score 0):

As you can see DisplayManagerShellCommand, like "ab-logging-enable", just use

```
adb shell cmd display ab-logging-enable
```